# How to pass partials to a Dust.js template

Tags: dust.js

I have consulted the Dust.js GitHub page and it says that I can pass partials to templates as shown below:

```
{@partial checkbox_title="JM"}
{>toggle/}
{/partial}
```

and like this:

```
{>toggle checkbox_title="Hi JM"/}
```

I've tried both and neither of them worked, so I used the following:

Parent:

```
{< checkbox_title}
Hi JM
{/checkbox_title} 
{>toggle/}
```

Child:

```
{+checkbox_title/}
```

The above works, except when I try to render a template using the following:

```
dust.render("toggle", base.push({checkbox_title:"hhhhhh"}),
    function(err, html) { console.log(html); });
```

Aim: to override the block in the child template using dust.render

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a template named `someTemplate` you can include it in another template using `{>someTemplate/}`. You can assign context with `{>someTemplate:someContext/}` and pass inline parameters with `{>someTemplate some_param="A parameter"/}`. Example:

```
<h1>{heading}</h1>
<p>{article}</p>
{>someTemplate/}
```

If you want to use blocks (they have the following syntax `{+blockName/}` or `{+blockName}Default block content{/blockName}` then you must define a template with the block, then include that template as a partial, then override the block. Example template with name "someTemplate":

```
<h1>{heading}</h1>
<p>{article}</p>
{+someBlock/}
```

Then override the block like so:

```
{>someTemplate/}
{<someBlock}
    My custom block content.
{/someBlock}
```

EDITS:

To customise the block outside of the template, create a context using `dust.makeBase`. This context object can be passed to `dust.render` in place of your templateData (dust does this internally anyway). Then add a block to the context using `context.shiftBlocks` with the argument being a hash with the blocks you want to override. Example:

```
var context = dust.makeBase(templateData).shiftBlocks({
    someblock: function (chunk, context) {
        return chunk.write('my new block content');
    }
});

dust.render('myTemplate', context, function (error, html) {
    console.log(html);
});
```

Some final comments: to be honest, I've not had a need to do this so far. I'd try to do as much with the template syntax as possible so that your templates can be understood on their own. Anyway, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon... but my question wasn't very clear, what I want to do is override the block using dust.render...

Comment: Ok, no probs. I've added in what you need...hopefully.