# Dust.js partial template

Tags: javascript, template-engine, dust.js

I try to follow the example 1 from (https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-little-less-know-language-constructs) tutorial. Then I do my testing as below:

partial.tl

```
{+greeting} Hola {/greeting}
{+world} World {/world}
```

Main.html

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="itemTemplate">
{>partial/}
</script>
```

But it didn't works. If you know how to do partial template, please show me how. Dust.js tutorial / guide is really hard to find on internet.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194366/how-to-pass-partials-to-a-dust-js-template

Comment: @KD Thanks for the link. But I still don't get it works. As I put in `{>partial/}`, my whole template become not working. If you know how, please show to me. Thanks.

Comment: @KD I just found that the problem is Dust.js cannot find `partial.tl`. I tried with `partial.dust`, but it is still the same. I am putting the `partial.tl` in the same directory as `main.html`, and dust.js in the js sub folder. Why is it cannot load? How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dust has to be compiled to JavaScript before you can execute it. .tl and .dust files are just source forms. If you are in a client environment there is a pretty good explanation here. [Basic Example of Client Side Templating with Dust.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356235/basic-example-of-client-side-templating-with-dust-js)